# How to export multiple variables in tool mode?

Tags: godot

How do I add multiple inputs for a single variable in tool mode like in the image below

[image]

closest I got was:

```
tool

export(Array) var T=[0,0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm I figured it out

```
tool

export(Vector2) var T;
```

A little tip for any future wanderers:

```
tool

export(Array) var T=[0,0];
```

From this click on the pencil item when modifying array variable & you can see all the data types and export them to see various functionalities

[image]

Comment: you should mark your own answer as the accepted answer :)